# How can I disable my headset's microphone and force Ubuntu to use my internal microphone?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

Whenever I plug in my headset, Ubuntu tries to use my headset's microphone, which is broken, so I'm not able to input audio while outputting audio to my headset. I've tried setting my internal microphone as the default audio input device via PulseAudio Volume Control, but it's labeled as "(Unplugged)", and doesn't pick up any audio.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, when your headset is in use, does it automatically disables an internal microphone?

Comment: Yeah it does, when I unplug it the internal microphone works fine though.

Comment: Perhaps related with this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1025388